# Menu [Timber] in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, timber

How to make a drop-down menu in Timber WordPress, the following is my code but is not showing as drop-down, also I am inserting an image how it looks now, the menu is horizontal menu
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UllKC.png)

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-2" id="mainNavigation">
<ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
{% for item in topmenu.items %}
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link {{ item.classes|join(' ') }} mx-2" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% if item.children %}
<ul class="nav-drop">
{% for child in item.children %}
<li class="nav-drop-item">
<a href="{{ child.link }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use menu.twig file with the following code:

```
{% if menu %}
    <ul>
        {% for item in items %}
            <li class="{{ item.classes | join(' ')}}">
                <a target="{{ item.target}}" href="{{ item.link}}">{{ item.title}}</a>
                {% include "menu.twig" with{'items':item.children} %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

and then inside the base.twig or inside the other file where you want to display the menu add the following code:

{% include "menu.twig" with{'items':menu.get_items} %}